# What is {empty set} x something with the product topology?

Tags: general-topology, product-space

The product topology is defined as the topology induced by the basis of the product of open sets from each of the original topologies.
From what I understand, then $\{\emptyset\}\times]a,b[$ is an open set of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the product topology, right? But what is this geometrically? I can't see what this is.

Comment: Empty cross anything is empty.

Comment: The set $\{ \emptyset \}$ has at most one topology. For any space $A$ you can show $\{\emptyset \} \times A$ is homeomorphic to $A$

Comment: Being "homeomorphic to" is intuitively the same as "looking like," so it just looks like $\mathbb{R}$. I should say that you're wrong in assuming $\{\emptyset \}$ is open. And thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition, the elements of $A\times B$ (for sets $A$ and $B$) are the ordered pairs $\langle a,b\rangle$ such that $a\in A$ and $b\in B.$ Since $a\in\emptyset$ is impossible, then $\emptyset\times B$ *has* no elements, meaning $\emptyset\times B=\emptyset,$ regardless of the set $B.$

The open sets of $\Bbb R^2$ in the product topology can be obtained from the basis $\{A\times B:A,B\text{ are open subsets of }\Bbb R\}.$ This will include elements of the form $\emptyset\times B=\emptyset,$ as well as $A\times\emptyset=\emptyset.$ However, it will *not* have any elements of the form $\{\emptyset\}\times B,$ since $\emptyset$ isn't an element of $\Bbb R.$

Comment: The question is asking about $\{\emptyset \} \times A$, not $\emptyset \times A$

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand your answer, but just to be sure, ∅ x O, where O is an open set of the topology on B is an open set of the product topology on A x B, right? Different from U x ∅, where U is an open set of the topology on B

Comment: Oh, dear! I misunderstood. I'll edit accordingly.

Comment: Ohhh okay, now I understand, thank you! I was mistaking ∅ with {∅}. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of $\{\emptyset\}$, I'll consider $\{*\}$ just to avoid confusion. It really doesn't matter, you can use anything instead of $*$. What matters is that $\{*\}$ is a singleton as a set.

Let $X$ be a topological space. Then, basis for topology of $\{*\}\times X$ is given by $\{ \{*\}\times U\mid U\subseteq X\ \text{open}\}$.

Define $f\colon X\to \{*\}\times X$ by $f(x) = (*,x)$ and $g\colon \{*\}\times X\to X$ by $g(*,x) = x$. Obviously, these functions are inverses of each other. They are also continuous, since for any $U\subseteq X$ open we have

$$f^{-1}(\{*\}\times U) = U,\ g^{-1}(U) = \{*\}\times U.$$

Thus, $X$ and $\{*\}\times X$ are homeomorphic.

If $X = \mathbb R$, instead of $*$ choose some real number $a$. Then $\{a\}\times\mathbb R$ is naturally a line embedded in $\mathbb R^2$. Here are examples for some different $a$'s:

[image]